# Deploying contract to jungle testnet wallet error

Tags: cleos, wallet, testnet

I am trying to `cleos set contract lonklytestt4 ./missions missions.wasm missions.abi` and getting:

```
Using correct URL, but when trying to set contract for user I get: Reading WASM from ./missions/missions.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3120006: No available wallet
```

I have no idea how to open wallet on jungle testnet, as I do not have it's name/password. Neither I'm able to create it through cleos. It just gives:

```
~/eos/build/programs/cleos/cleos -u http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888/ wallet create -n testwallat --to-console
Error 3120000: Wallet exception
```

When I am trying to connect to jungle testnet wallet, it says:

```
cleos --wallet-url http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888 set contract lonklytest22 ~/devel/missions/
Reading WASM from /Users/lonkly/devel/missions.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3110002: Missing Wallet API Plugin
Ensure that you have eosio::wallet_api_plugin added to your node's configuration!
Otherwise specify your wallet location with --wallet-url argument!
Error Details:
Wallet is not available
```

So I guess wallet should not be required to sign transactions on jungle test? How does the process look like in general?
I have created user on testnet, gave him some EOS from faucet, then I need to set contract, but what am I missing?

P.S: I am using `alias cleos='cleos -u http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888'` so missing `-u` can be disregarded.

Comment: Did you created wallet on local system? make sure the key you used to create  you wallet should be use to create you account, that is why  I said store your key very carefully. I created account on test net and run like:                                                                      `cleos --url http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888 push action eosio.token transfer '{"from":"myaccount","to":"sender_account","quantity":"20.0000 EOS","memo":"my first transfer"}' -p myaccount`    and this is working fine.

Comment: `cleos --wallet-url http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888 set contract lonklytest22 ~/devel/missions/` contract are not set on wallet urls, our wallet are linked with our account. So  first you need to link you wallet with your account, if you do that successfully set your contract like:                                                         
`cleos --url http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888 set contract your_account_name $path_to_your_contracts(where your cpp and hpp files lies)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create a account on jungle testnet, you should also have a wallet already created in your system, in  my case wallet path is:

**/home/nirdesh.choudhary/eosio-wallet**
after that you have to link you wallet to your account , if your keosd running port 8900 you can do like :
make sure you store your keys in secure location

```
private_key = "your_private_key"
echo $private_key|cleos --wallet-url http: 127.0.0.1:8900 wallet import  -n myaccount
```

***myaccount*** is the account you have created on jungle testnet

I have written all this in my jungle.sh file. You can also write a bash file so that everytime you don't have to import your wallet and whole repeatitive work again.